# ModifyMode is not working in editableGeojsonLayer in nebula.gl

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, nebula.gl

This may sound a bit stupid, but I am trying to use ModifyMode under the mode property of EditableGeoJsonLayer, but the adjustable handles do not appear, as it is supposed to in the "Geojson Editor" example posted on nebula.gl website. It would have been convenient if there were more examples regarding the editableGeojsonLayer API reference. This what I am trying to do:

```
new (EditableGeoJsonLayer as any)({
            id: 'geojson',
            data: featureState.data,
            mode: ModifyMode,
            selectedFeatureIndexes,
            onEdit: ({updatedData}):any => {
                setFeatureState({ 
                    data: updatedData 
                });
                
            },
            pickable: true,
            pickingRadius: 15,
            //onClick: data => InfoWindow(data.object.properties, data.coordinate, "New Shape", "PointView"),
 }
```

Also after further tests, none of alter modes are working, but all draw modes and view modes are working fine

Comment: Btw, you don't need a `SelectionLayer`, that's for selecting using a mouse **drawing**. Just use `pickable: true`, `selectedFeatureIndexes` and `onClick`, so you can click the features. I don't think [`dontknownothing`'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70046774/7365866) is good

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the feature is selected ,as a matter of fact, make it can be seleted at first.

Comment: This would be better as a comment. I understand that you haven't enough reputation for that, but it would still be better as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have a selectionLayer when using ModifyMode. You must select the polygon before you can modify it. When the polygon/line is selected you should see the corner, and new point addition, blocks to drag-and-drop.

`selectedFeatureIndexes` should be an array of selected polygons ids. You can set this array in your selectionLayer `onSelect` by taking advantage of the pickingInfos parameter.

Here is a sample selectionLayer

```
const selectionLayer = new SelectionLayer({
  id: "selection",
  selectionType: "rectangle",

  onSelect: ({ pickingInfos }) => {
  
    // use pickingInfos to set the SelectedFeatureIndexes
    setSelectedFeatureIndexes(pickingInfos.map((pi) => pi.index));

    // any other functionality for selecting, like adding id's to state
  },
  layerIds: ["geojson"],

  getTentativeFillColor: () => [255, 0, 255, 100],
  getTentativeLineColor: () => [0, 0, 255, 255],
  lineWidthMinPixels: 3,
});
```